# How to randomize 4 filtered outputs from a text document

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files

I'm working on a project that needs 4 random outputs. One for each grade in text file

The text file is organized using " /" as a split character so it can be read by a datagridview
Its set up like this
First/ Last/ Grade/
John/ Doe/ 9/

My code has 4 text boxes (one for each grade output)

My code outputs 4 random outputs to the textboxes but im having trouble constraining them to certain grades

This randomization needs to read from a .txt file with " /" splitting "columns" for the datagridview to read
filter the text file based on certain characters
and then output one random option (one time for each grade) from the filtered text file

This is my Current Code for the random outputs
I haven't been able to get any further

```
private void buttonRandomWinner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            Random r = new Random();

            var randomLineNumber2 = r.Next(0, lines2.Length - 1);
            var freshmanWinner = lines2[randomLineNumber2];
            textBoxRandomFreshman.Text = freshmanWinner;

            var randomLineNumber3 = r.Next(0, lines2.Length - 1);
            var sophmoreWinner = lines2[randomLineNumber3];
            textBoxRandomSophmore.Text = sophmoreWinner;

            var randomLineNumber4 = r.Next(0, lines2.Length - 1);
            var juniorWinner = lines2[randomLineNumber4];
            textBoxRandomJunior.Text = juniorWinner;

            var randomLineNumber5 = r.Next(0, lines2.Length - 1);
            var seniorWinner = lines2[randomLineNumber5];
            textBoxRandomSenior.Text = seniorWinner;
```

this is my current code for sending my information to the datagridview

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] entries = line.Split('/');

                Student newStudent = new Student(entries[0], entries[1], entries[2], entries[3]);
                
                newStudent.FirstName = entries[0];
                newStudent.LastName = entries[1];
                newStudent.Grade = entries[2];
                newStudent.Points = entries[3];

                students.Add(newStudent);

                
            }
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"{student.FirstName} {student.LastName} {student.Grade} {student.Points} ");
            }

            //lines.Add("John/ Doe/ 9/");
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
            Console.ReadLine();

            leaderboardDatagridview.DataSource = students;
```